# Update the value on input blur in react-final-form

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

I'm using `react-number-format` with `react-final-form`. My component looks like this:

```
const CurrencyInput = props => {
  return (
    <NumberFormat
      thousandSeparator=" "
      decimalScale="2"
      isNumericString={true}
      fixedDecimalScale={true}
      allowNegative={false}
      autoComplete="off"
      onBlur={props.input.onBlur}
      onFocus={props.input.onFocus}
      onChange={value => props.input.onChange(value)}
    />
  );
};
```

`react-number-format` has `allowLeadingZeros` prop, which strips leading zeros on input blur. How can I update the value in `react-final-form` accordingly? If I type zeros before the number, the value in the input itself is corrected on blur, but the value stored by `react-final-form` stays with zeros.

Here is my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-form-wreact-number-format-4kmpy?fontsize=14).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`react-number-format` does not call onChange after formatting the string.

But `react-number-format` has a prop called `onValueChange` which gets triggered after formatting the string:

Example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-form-wreact-number-format-bmeg9

Besides that, I suggest storing the value as a number in state and not as a string.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I took your example, but change `formattedValue` to `floatValue` to remove blank spaces in thousands: `onValueChange={({ floatValue }) => props.input.onChange(floatValue)}`. Could you please tell how I can store the value as a number instead of a string?